# Active Storage File Not Found error when trying to use ImageProcessing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, minimagick

I keep getting

```
ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError (ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError):
app/models/service.rb:24:in `process_images'
```

When trying to load an image into ImageProcessing::MiniMagick using
`ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(self.image.download)`

I have also tried

`ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(self.image)`
`ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(self.image.attachment)`
`ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(self.image.attachment.download)`
`ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(self.image.blob)`

ImageProcessing doesn't like those as its looking for a url so I tried using a url as well like this
`url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.image, only_path: true)` and passing that in instead of self.image
When I do that I get the error

```
failed with error:
convert: unable to open image `rails/active_storage/blobs/foo...`
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction.

here is the relevant part of my Model as it looks now.

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :featured_image, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :process_images
  after_save :process_images

  private  
  def process_images 
    url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.image, only_path: true)
    pipeline1 = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(url)
    #can't continue until I load an image
  end
end
```

I have also called the method from the controller. I made the model method not private and called it and it solved the nil attachment issue. The following but then I get this error.
`ArgumentError (string contains null byte):` flagged at this line.
pipeline1.resize_to_limit(400,400).convert("jpg").call

*All I'm trying to do is resize images when the instance is created or updated and then save the processed image as the main attachment.*

Comment: Can you try this? `ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, self.image.key))`

Comment: Patricio thanks that worked. If you're available can you please explain why this method of passing an image source works and none of the other methods did?

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation *"The source object needs to responds to `.path`, or be a `String`, a `Pathname`, or a `Vips::Image/MiniMagick::Tool object`"*, none of the arguments you provided met the requirements.

My approach was to get the full path of your ActiveStorage file, for this we can use `ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, <attachment>)`, and then use this as an argument in the `ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source` method.

That's why the following works:

```
ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, self.image.key))
```

Comment: On Rails 6.0.3.3 I get this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `path_for' for #<ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service:0x00007ffb08017a10>):

Comment: @IvanRaszl Well, it seems you are using an S3 bucket, so it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably not related to `MiniMagick`, but to `ActiveStorage`. Avoid attaching attachments inside transactions and all will run smooth. This applies to migrations, seeds or callbacks.

What I finally did to avoid my logic being wrapped inside a transaction is to run the logic inside a thread:

```rb
Thread.new do
  # your logic here
end.join
```

Comment: This helped me as I was using a transaction to create an active storage attachment and then generating variants. Once I remove the transaction, it works. This also seems to be a Rails 7 issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706012/ruby-on-rails-7-abort-rollback-when-you-have-nested-database-transactions?noredirect=1#comment128443002_72706012