# Ruby on Rails 7 ABORT/ROLLBACK when you have nested database transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions, ruby-on-rails-7

I just updated to Rails 7 and am encountering this issue that used to work with Rails 6.1.

```
# new_object_controller.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  new_object = NewObject.create!(params)
  DoSomethingWithNewObjectService.new(new_object).do_something
end

# do_something_with_new_object_service.rb
def do_something
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    new_object.update!(blah_atributes)
  end
end
```

When I step through the code with pry-debugger, I get these lines although they don't quite make sense to me:

```
From: .../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:331 ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TransactionManager#within_new_transaction:

it goes into lines 332, 336, 342 basically aborting and finally going into

TRANSACTION (5.1ms)  ROLLBACK
From: .../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:27 ActiveSupport::Concurrency::LoadInterlockAwareMonitor#synchronize:
```

The code actually goes through the end of the controller and tries to go to the next step but everything within the database transaction is rolled back.

Removing both the ActiveRecord::Base.transaction fixes the issue. Googling does not show much reasoning except this [Rails 7 adds optional transaction arguments to with_lock](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/03/23/rails-7-adds-lock_with.html).

This has many implications on design pattern as I use database transactions in small ruby classes that gets used in many places. If you can only have one transaction going at one time, that means that you need to be aware of any code executing within that transaction to ensure that there are no nested transactions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does it error out in rails 7 whereas it works in rails 6.1? What's the solution to chaining database transactions?

Comment: See the documentation at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions. Does this answer your question?